# Resistor losses in heat

Tags: resistors, series, power-consumption, loss

I am trying to understand the power lost via heat (friction) from a resistor as opposed to what flows through and is available for the next component in series, and how I estimate this.

I have read a lot of articles on this and they all seem to calculate heat dissipation total consumption -- i.e. use Ohm's law to work out current then multiply by voltage, but if this was true then there would be nothing left for the next component in series to use.

I am sure I am missing something here  but in my mind I imagine a resistor connected to a battery and the total consumed power would be Heat Lost + power allowed through the resistor.

The reason this is important to me is for when we are dealing with low power battery projects I don't know how effective using a resistor would be in actually saving power.

My other thought is about Christmas lights in series that get dimmer the further along the string you go meaning some but not all the power is consumed by each.

Comment: When caculating the power consumed by a resistor, you use the voltage across the resistor, not the full voltage applied to the circuit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you "multiply by the voltage", that is the voltage across the resistor.  If your circuit was supplied with 12v and you saw 3v across the resistor, that would leave 9v available for doing other work around the circuit.

The thing you multiply the voltage by is the current, and the current is the same everywhere in a series circuit--it goes through everything.  And you can see this, because your Christmas light string does *not* get dimmer as you go down the wire (assuming each bulb is the same).

Comment: I still does not separate out energy lost by the resistor in heat vs what simply passes through it. For example if there is only one resistor/bulb then the voltage drop is the total voltage so then 100% of all the power consumed is lost as heat? Then why is there still power flowing out the other end? Isn't the heat just a result of that power passing through (friction) I am missing something @gbarry sorry

Comment: @AndrewT In the end everything turns to heat. If you have two 6V 1A bulbs in series and connect them to 12V battery, both bulbs have 6V over then and 1A flowing through them. If you replace one or both bulbs with 6 ohm resistors, exactly same currents and voltages are present. Though in the case of bulbs, part of the energy is emitted as visible light so not everything is immediately turned into heat, like with resistors. But power taken from 12V battery and power going into bulbs/resistors is.

Comment: @AndrewT "For example if there is only one resistor/bulb then the voltage drop is the total voltage so then 100% of all the power consumed is lost as heat?" – Yes. To be precise, if you have a voltage source connected to a resistor, and nothing else in the circuit, then 100% of the power coming from the voltage source will be consumed by the resistor and converted into heat. "Then why is there still power flowing out the other end?" – There isn't. In the circuit I described, electric power only goes into the resistor; no electric power comes out of it.

Comment: @AndrewT By the way, the notion of power going through wires and components is a difficult one, because different ways of analyzing a circuit produce different answers that seem to contradict each other. For example, if I connect a battery to a resistor, which terminal of the battery does the power come from—the positive, the negative, or both? Unfortunately, there's no single correct answer to that question. Different ways of analyzing the circuit produce different answers. It's very confusing until you learn all of the details.

Comment: Thank you  @Tanner Swett Its starting to make sense now "electric power only goes into the resistor; no electric power comes out of it." I was thinking about how that could be true given that current is flowing then I remembered P=VI so regardless of the current through if the voltage after the resister is 0 then the power is zero. Thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 3):

When you have one or more components in series driven by a voltage source, the same current flows through the entire circuit. The current will be determined by the voltage and the total resistance of all elements added together. The voltage across each element is determined by its resistance, and each element will dissipate power according to Ohm's law P = V * I. If the elements are resistors, the power will result in heat, but if they are lamps, some of that power will produce light, and if they are motors, there could be mechanical power.

All the voltages on the elements will total to the applied voltage. And if you add another element in series, the current through the string will be reduced by the total resistance, and the voltage across each element will be in proportion to the individual resistances.

Comment: Thanks @PStechPaul perhaps its a terminology thing but it still feels like you are describing how much power can flow through and not how much is dissipated/lost in heat. If I place 120ohm resistor in front of an LED (at 5v) the led can consume 4ma of or 20mw of power based on ohms law but how much was also lost by the resistor?

Comment: You are assuming that the LED consumes 20 mW based on 5V and the 120 ohm resistor (which would actually be 40 mA). But the voltage on the LED is probably about 2V, and the resistor will drop the remaining 3V. So the current will be more like 3/120 = 25 mA, and LED will consume 50 mW.

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure I am missing something here but in my mind I imagine a resistor connected to a battery and the total consumed power would be Heat Lost + power allowed through the resistor.

The electrical power consumed by the resistor and that dissipated as heat are one and the same.

> The reason this is important to me is for when we are dealing with low power battery projects I don't know how effective using a resistor would be in actually saving power.

A resistor does not save electrical power - only dissipates it as heat.

In your LED example, the resistor is used to drop the voltage applied across the LED / limit the current flowing through it. The resistor dissipates heat in the process while the LED, on its part, dissipates light.

The law of conservation of energy states that energy can neither be created nor destroyed - only converted from one form to another.